# Use module variable without pointing to it

Tags: python, variables, module

I am having a code like that:

```
>> from xmodule import defines
>> print defines.VARIABLE_ONE
>>> 123
```

What I'd like to achieve is making the `VARIABLE_ONE` defined in the `defines` module like it would be defined in my main file so I could simply use:

```
>> from xmodule import defines
>> print VARIABLE_ONE
>>> 123
```

Is this possible, or I'd rather have to always point to the `defines` module?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want this:

```
from xmodule.defines import VARIABLE_ONE
```

Assuming `xmodule` is package and `defines` is a module in that package.

See the [`Packages`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#packages) section of the documentation for more details on importing packages and submodules of packages.

Note that all the normal rules for importing names from modules apply here; you can import all the names from `defines` using `*`:

```
from xmodule.defines import *
```

Note that in general it's [not a good idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23810425/best-way-to-import-modules-in-python) to use the `from <module> import *` pattern. Though it seems that the `defines` module is just defining a bunch of constants, which is one case where it's usually ok to use that pattern.

Comment: Thats exactly what I needed. Thank you. Btw. just to make the things clear - you can edit your answer so if anyone would like to import all of the variables at once: `from xmodule.defines import *`

Comment: @Lucas I added that in, along with a note that generally using that pattern isn't recommended. (I think that in this particular case it's fine, though).